# calling _analyze with python for elasticsearch 6.x

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

How to perform the calling of

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "german_analyzer",
  "text": "kann"
}
```

in python elastic search 6.x api?

I tried

```
def get_es():

    # Variables for Elasticsearch host+port
    es_host = 'localhost'
    es_port = 9200

    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': es_host, 'port': es_port}])
    return es

if __name__ == '__main__':

    es = get_es()
    body={
      "analyzer": "german_analyzer",
      "text": "kann"
    }
    result = es.search(index="faq-kbaid-de-index", body=body,
                               size=1)
    i=1
```

it gives exception

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [analyzer].')
```

Answer (score 3):

`es.search()` calles `_search`. You can call `_analyze` via [elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient). Replace the `.search` line with

```
result = es.indices.analyze(index="faq-kbaid-de-index", body=body,
                           size=1)
```